# Formula Cell converting to Error Cell in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, xlsx

i am using apache poi to access excel, when ever i am using any formula that row is getting converted to error row.

```
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("D://Book.xlsx"); 
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

      XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(6);
      XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(4);
      cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
      cell.setCellFormula("LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>\"\"),ROW(A:A))");
      workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
      FormulaEvaluator evaluator =   workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
      CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);

      switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println("Boolean");
            System.out.println(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.println("Num");
            System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println("String");
            System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            System.out.println("Blank");
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            System.out.println("Error");
            Byte b = cellValue.getErrorValue();
            System.out.println(b.intValue());
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
            System.out.println("Formula");
            break;
    }   
      workbook.close();
      System.out.println("written successfully");
```

it is giving following as output
    Error
    15
    written successfully

but i am expecting that formula block to be executed. but every time it is executing error case. 
My Excel sheet contains simple row like:

```
a   1
b   2
a   3
b   4
d   5
r   6
g   7
q   8
y   9
```

please tell me what part i am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))` uses an not documented feature of Excels [LOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb#bmvector_form).

The part `1/(A:A<>"")` evaluates to `{1;1;1;1;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;...}`. If the cell in `A` is `<>""`, then `1` (`1/TRUE`), else `#DIV/0!` (`1/FALSE`).

But as of it is documented:

> Syntax
>
> LOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_vector, [result_vector])
>
> lookup_vector    Required. A range that contains only one row or one
>   column. The values in lookup_vector can be text, numbers, or logical
>   values.

Error values are not mentioned here!

And:

> Important: The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending
>   order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, LOOKUP
>   might not return the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text are
>   equivalent.

Whether `{1;1;1;1;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;...}` really is in ascending order is unclear!

So this will evaluate as expected in Excel. If you would write the workbook and opening it with Excel, the Formula `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),ROW(A:A))` would be in `E7` and would work as expected.

But with other `Evaluators` like the one from apache poi, which observe the evaluation rules exactly, it must not work.

With your data example, where I assume the values 1 to 9 are in column `B`,

```
cell.setCellFormula("LOOKUP(MAX(B:B),B:B,B:B)");
```

will evaluate as expected.

Surely it is not what you want - to get last filled cell in column `A`. This could also be achieved with array formulas. But while apache poi can apply array formulas to the sheet, as far as I know, it will not evaluate array formulas until now.

Comment: ya that part is working, thanks
i also want to get this result on java console, like say in E7, 8 is in excel , so i need 8 from java.

Comment: Like I have mentioned already in my answer, this is not possible using `FormulaEvaluator` from apache poi. If the need is to get the last filled row in column `A`, then loop through all present rows and check if a value is in cell(0).

Comment: If you can be sure, that Excel has evaluated this formula already, then you can `cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()` from the formula cell and then if this is `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`, `cell.getNumericCellValue()`. But then you cannot set the formula in your program. The formula must already be in the sheet while opening.